# SharePoint Framework property pane

Tags: spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

I have been playing around with SPFx and was wondering about the property pane controls. Are they specifically meant for configuring a web part or do they also serve as a type of input form for the web part? I suspect they are just for configuration since that is what they are in SP 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the classic webparts, they are designed for configuration of that SPFx webpart.